# Getting 404 notifications in internet explorer while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, debugging

If I debug with Firefox and some image is missing, then I am able to see the following error on the console; That's what I want in Internet Explorer (10), but I'm not getting any errors:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - blahblahblah/myapp/img/clear.png"

So if I'm debugging with IE I'm not getting these important notifications. I've tried to enable all the stuff related to enabling script debugging like disable friendly http errors, enable script debugging and so on. But on the Console for IE (F12) the error never appears.

The only way to be notified is by going to the Network tab at the console and click on the "Start capturing" button, so there I am able to see the 404 lines, but that's not the best way as I'd like the errors to be sown like Firefox does, in the Console error log.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the IE11 F12 tools don't display network errors in the console. It's something that is high on our backlog that we hope to get to soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the difference between the various browser's development tools. Internet Explorer has always had a particularly weak set. The best in my opinion is Chrome's, though Firefox *with* Firebug is not bad. Firefox on its own is weaker than Internet Explorer, in my opinion.

Regardless, you can debug with whatever browser you want, so probably your best bet, if you like the Firefox dev tools better, is to just switch your debug browser to Firefox in Visual Studio. Just click the "Play"-style arrow button that shows "Internet Explorer" currently and choose another browser installed on your system.